# How to fill a 3D Matrix with arrays of different dimensions?

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 3D matrix that holds information in the format:

```
    """
        The data below is in a text file
Part#1
parameterA 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30 parameterB 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 30 10 parameterC 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20 parameterD 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30
Part#2 
parameterA 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20 parameterB 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 parameterC 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 30 30 10 20 parameterD 10 10 20 20 20 30 10 10 20 20 30
Part#3
parameterA 10 20 10 30 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 parameterB 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30 parameterC 10 20 10 30 10 10 10 20 10 20 10 parameterD 10 20 10 10 30 10 20 10 30 10 20 parameterE 10 20 10 10 10 10 30 30 30 10 20    
    """
```

The data should be separated like this (just showing the format of the indexes of the DS):

matrix[index for parts][index for parameters][index for line of values]

Being each part in brackets an index in some type of frame, so I can call them individually for instance:

```
matrix[0][0] = 10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30
```

keeping in mind this format:

```
matrix[part#1][parameter][10 10 20 10 10 30 10 30 10 20 30]
```

The function below parses the file, but is not doing it correctly

```
def parse_file_into_matrix(inputFilename):
    
    with open(inputFilename) as inputFile:
        content = inputFile.readlines()
        content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    
    lines =[]             
    parts = []            
    parameterNames = []    
    parameterValues = []   
    
    # separates the runs from each line of elements and its values and adds it to a new list "lines"
    for i in range(len(content)):
        # Keeps the run numbers if true otherwise assign an element/values line into lines
        if re.match(r"Part #[0-3]+",content[i]):
            part = int(re.findall(r"Part #([0-3]+)",content[i])[0])
            parts.append("Part #"+ str(runs))
        else:
            lines.append(content[i])

    # will contain everything categorized  (parts/Parameter/Values)      
    matrix_3D = np.arange(len(parts)) 
        
    # separates the parameter name from its values and assigns each one to 
    # a list of parameters and a list of values based on its order
    for j in range(0, len(lines)):
        parameter = lines[j].strip().split(' ')[0]
        parameterNames.append(parameter)
        values = list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, lines[j].strip().split()[1:])))
        parameterValues.append(values)
        
        df_parts = pd.DataFrame(parts)
        df_pv = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([parameterNames, parameterValues]))
        df_pv = np.asarray(df_pv)
        
    return df_pv   #it only shows what I have been able to merged, I haven't been able to add the parts to it
    
    
pprint(parse_file_into_matrix("sample.txt"))
```

The output I get for this function right now is:

```
array([['Part#1', list([])],
       ['parameterA',
        list([10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30])],
       ['Part#2', list([])],
       ['parameterA',
        list([10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30])],
       ['Part#3', list([])],
       ['parameterA',
        list([10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30, 10, 20])],
       ['', list([])]], dtype=object)
```

here is the issue:

The parameter values go along with the values (numerical sequence per string parameter), these two lists have the same length as they correspond to each other. so if I take the list of parameters and the list of values and separated  those two arrays from the array that contain parts, I get 13 lines (13 lines containing parameters and values) which divided by 3 partitions or parts gives me 4.33 lines per part. so I will either have to round the value I get as a result of a division meaning I will be truncated a significant amount of lines in the original data to fit an even length among all partitions, or as shown above I will have to just add the extra lines to the last partition, which may end up in discrepancies.

**note**.- the length of the lines (parameter/values) is always the same horizontally; however, it is not the same if we see this vertically (number of lines).

so if I print the outputs individually I get this:

```
matrix_3D = parse_file_into_matrix("sample.txt")   
print(matrix_3D[0])
print(matrix_3D[1])
```

Output:

```
['Part#1' list([])] # <- if this was the case the sublist in part should be the parameter with the corresponding list of values for that parameter 
['parameterA'
 list([10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30])]
```

if get to the right data structure that can hold the data I will be able to check specific sequences in a particular partition and parameter, something like this:  [part1][a] which would give me the entire sequence: 10 10 20 30 30 and if I want to plot that I would be able to see it graphically too.

The output above is the closest I've gotten but still is not the right output, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please paste all your traceback informations.

Comment: If it is not necessary that you require a 3d matrix, then you can create a dictionary.

Comment: I already asked that before, and the answer with the dctionary was really helpful. However, I was advice that I needed to have the values and the divisions (parts) as illustrated above, so I can do a couple of calculations, as well as plotting the data. the Dictionary is still helpful, but I already have that. i've been trying with data frames too, since matrices don't see to allow arrays of strings in the matrix (that's what it keeps me looking for so many ways, and still cannot solve this)

Comment: Are your strings literally "parameterA", etc? Do they ever change? Numpy works best on homogeneous arrays of numbers. It can deal with strings, but it's much better if you can keep your strings and numbers separate.

Comment: No. The names are a sample in the post, and yes they remain there. I already merged parameters and values using dataframes and then converting it into a bumpy array, but then I get stuck on how to merged the parts with the rest as they have to be added every 250+ times or as in the example every 4 times (the length of the parameters list per partition)

Comment: And the issue is because of the same is like dealing with 2 arrays of strings plus different dimensions

Comment: Here os another idsue I encouentered if I have even lengths like in the example 12/3=4 the matrix cam be created and reshape (not with the input I needed though!) But if I have legths like this 17/4= 4.25 which is the case of my lengths. it crashes right there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested dictionaries could help access the data in the manner you specified, that is matrix['PartName']['paramName'] = [1,2,3,..]

Try this:

```
def myparse(inputFilename):
    with open(inputFilename) as inputFile:
        lines = inputFile.readlines()
        lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
        matrix = {} # nested dictionary

        curPart = None
        for line in lines:
            if 'Part' in line:
                currPart = line
                matrix[currPart]={}
            else:
                curParamName = None
                partParams = {} # the list of parameters and their values for the current part
                pars = line.split()
                for p in pars:
                    try:
                        # if it is an int, it belongs to the last read parameter name
                        p = int (p)
                        partParams[curParamName].append(p)
                    except ValueError:
                        # if the cast to int fails it means it is a new parameter name
                        curParamName = p
                        partParams[curParamName] = []

                matrix[currPart] = partParams
        return matrix

matrix = myparse('sample.txt')
print 'Matrix:\n___________\n', matrix, '\n'
print 'Matrix[Part #1]:\n___________\n', matrix['Part #1'], '\n'
print 'Matrix[Part #1][ParameterA]:\n___________\n', matrix['Part #1']['parameterA']
```

Output:

```
Matrix:
___________
{'Part #3': {'parameterE': [10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterD': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterA': [10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10], 'parameterC': [10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10], 'parameterB': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30]}, 'Part #2': {'parameterD': [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30], 'parameterA': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterC': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterB': [10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10]}, 'Part #1': {'parameterD': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30], 'parameterA': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30], 'parameterC': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterB': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10]}}

Matrix[Part #1]:
___________
{'parameterD': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30], 'parameterA': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30], 'parameterC': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20], 'parameterB': [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10]}

Matrix[Part #1][ParameterA]:
___________
[10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30]
```